# IF Statement Returning Incorrect Function

Tags: php

Hash Value of URL is Set in Cookies on Previous Page, then Redirects to the Login Page. If the value of the cookie is null or if it has a value the result is still 'else'.

```
$shareURL = $_COOKIE["redirect"];
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

  if (is_null($shareURL)) { 
        function Redirect($url, $permanent = false){
        header('Location: ' . $url, true, $permanent ? 301 : 302);
        exit();
      }
        header('Location: /dashboard');

  }else{
        function Redirect($url, $permanent = false){
        header('Location: ' . $url, true, $permanent ? 301 : 302);
        exit();
  }
        Redirect('/120x220x90', false);
     } 


    }else{
    }
```

Comment: Try empty() instead

Comment: @NigelRen still returns else even though the cookie is null

Comment: Why declare `Redirect` twice? What's `var_dump($shareURL)` show?

Comment: @user3783243 i have $shareURL echo'd in the html, it displays nothing. The cookie value in the browser is set to null. The variable is working because if i change the value to 'hello' then 'hello' is echo'd instead.

Comment: var_dump returns      string(4) "null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string(4) "null"`

indicates your variable is not a data type `null`. Rather it is a string containing `null`. This should work.

```
if (is_null($shareURL) || $shareURL == 'null') {
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not want to create two functions, doing the same thing. You might consider modifying your codes similar to the below script and it would work:

```
function Redirect($url, $permanent = false)
{
    header('Location: ' . $url, true, $permanent ? 301 : 302);
    exit();
}

$shareURL = $_COOKIE["redirect"];
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    if (is_null($shareURL)) {
        Redirect('/dashboard', false);
    } else {
        Redirect('/120x220x90', false);
    }
} else {

}
```

Comment: Still returns else unfortunately